# Media-query is not working on this image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors, media-queries

```
  <div class="col-lg-6" >
   <img src = "iphone6.png" id="dog-mobile" alt="phone">
   </div>

#dog-mobile{
    height:600px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    }
@media(max-width:1000){
    #dog-mobile{
         position: static;
         transform: rotate(0deg); 
        }
    }
```

<media query is not working on this image, below 1000px the image should be positioned static and should be straight but it is not so. It also has a Bootstrap class of grid i.e. col-lg-6[screenshot of output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hdpZ.png) >

Comment: You forgot to specify the unit. It should be `(max-width:1000px)`

Comment: can you please share html too...

Comment: After mentioning the unit as 1000px it is now working and without including the screen type; What does screen type do?. Thankyou....

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.
Please refrain from sharing links to screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this line in your HTML page inside `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also change CSS as given below:-

```
#dog-mobile{
    height:600px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #dog-mobile{
         position: static;
         transform: rotate(0deg); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: change this line :- `@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {` also